# Restricting foreach with json to only specific field

Tags: php, json, foreach

I have this function

```
$url = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/search?q='.spaces($query).'&fields='.$fields.'&limit='.$limit.'&until='.$until);
 $j = json_decode($url);
  foreach($j->data as $v) {
}
```

I want to restrict th search to only those data that has as type = status.

I tried to do so:

```
 foreach($j->data->type =='status' as $v) {
```

But it returns an error.
What is the easy - clean way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

You need to iterate over all of them an check *inside* the loop:

```
foreach ($j->data as $v) {
  if ($v->type == "status") {
    // Do whatever you were going to do...
  }
}
```

It is possible to use `array_filter()` to remove the values you aren't interested in before iterating, but probably not worth the extra effort since the performance gain would be minimal to non-existant.